# Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies for the FacebookSDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, jar

I want to do Login with facebook. I am following this [Steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).It's all working perfact. But when I am going to `Create a new Android Project with Facebook Login` STEP-6 into above link I got the error of the `Jar mismatch`.

when I create new android application that time there is no any errors, but when add the **`FacebookSDK`** to the newly create project. that time it gives

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies  |   Unknown Android Dependency Problem
```

I tried everything to change the java compiler level but not getting.

I tried project properties > Java compiler > In this level I do all changes of the java versions, but not success.

any help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try to remove the `android-support-v4.jar` file from the **libs** folder of your project.

Good Luck.

Comment: It worked!. Can you please give more explanation on what is the problem?

Comment: FB definitely includes the same jar. This trick worked, but I still got errors, quickfix said to add appcompat_v7 to project (which was already there oddly), but did it anyway, and all good.

Answer (score 19):

If there is any **JAR** file with same name in the **libs** folder of the **Library** and your **Project**, they must have the same size(same jar files).

If now just replace one of them with the other

Comment: Perfect solution for `Jar mismatch!` Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

The Android FacebookSDK includes its own version of `android-support-v4.jar`, and it's most likely the conflicting `jar`.

Open project preferences, select `Java Build Path` and remove `android-support-v4.jar` from the root, and things should compile well again.

Answer (score 0):

I think there exist a better solution for solving this problem than removing the android-support jar being used. It might cause some other errors to your project. I solved this problem by removing the support jar of fb sdk and then updating its support library to the version we have in our project and then add the library project to your project and it will compile with out any errors

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `FacebookSDK` brings with it its own version of `android-support-v4.jar.` You may remedy this by following these steps:

1. Delete `android-support-v4.jar` from your own android project
2. Delete `android-support-v4.jar` from `appcompat_v7`
3. Copy `android-support-v4.jar` from your `FacebookSDK` project
4. Paste this copied jar in the places where you deleted the others

This is less risky then outright deleting the jars from the two projects. This not only remedies SHA-1 hash issues. It will also help with `res` errors that may popup in your `appcompat_v7` project post addition of the `FacebookSDK` into your project.